# If Statement on Dict

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

Trying to write function that returns True if `word` in `list` and only made up of letters in `hand`. I am fine on checking if `word` in `list`, but cannot figure out how to iterate through to check the second part. The below is incorrectly returning True:

```
    word = 'chayote'
    hand = {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'u': 2, 't': 2, 'y': 1, 'h': 1, 'z': 1, 'o': 2}
    list = ['peach', 'chayote']

    def ValidWord(word, hand, list):
        if word in list:
            for i in word:
                if i in hand:
                    return True
                return False
        else:
            return False

ValidWord(word, hand, list)
```

Comment: You need to fail early, and succeed only if you don't fail. You're doing the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this would be to use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), like this

```
from collections import Counter
def is_valid_word(word, hand, list):
    if word in my_list:
        return len(Counter(word) - Counter(hand)) == 0
    return False

my_list = ['peach', 'chayote']
hand = {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'u': 2, 't': 2, 'y': 1, 'h': 1, 'z': 1, 'o': 2}

print is_valid_word("chayote", hand, my_list)
# False
print is_valid_word("peach", hand, my_list)
# False
```

Comment: Does the number in the dictionary matter?

Comment: @Gnijuohz I didnt get what you mean... :(

Comment: 'only made up of letters in hand', but not necessarily the same number of letter?

Comment: @Gnijuohz Then why bother storing the `count`? ;)

Comment: Not sure... Your answer should be the correct one if the count matters.

Comment: @Gnijuohz I believe so.

Comment: To clarify, yes, the count value for each key in hand matters. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) to do this, might be more concise:

```
if all(i in hand for i in words):
    return True
```

If the count matters, see @thefourtheye's answer.

Comment: If you want to turn inline code into a link, include the backticks when you highlight the code before you hit the link button.

Comment: Nope. `my_list = ['aa']; hand = {'a': 1}` It will return `True`.

Comment: @thefourtheye that's what I meant. It should return True? Now I'm confused... Not sure if the value of the dictionary is important to OP

Answer (score 0):

You can change the returns inside for loop:

```
word = 'chayote'
word2 = 'peach'
hand = {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'u': 2, 't': 2, 'y': 1, 'h': 1, 'z': 1, 'o': 2, 'e': 2} # I added 'e' so chayote is true and peach is false
list = ['peach', 'chayote']

def ValidWord(word, hand, list):
    if word in list:
        for i in word:
            if i not in hand:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(ValidWord(word, hand, list))
print(ValidWord(word2, hand, list))
```

Comment: Nope. `my_list = ['aa']; hand = {'a': 1}` It will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

If count matters expand Gnijuohz' solution:

```
def ValidWord(word,hand,list):
  return word in list and all(i in hand for i in word) and all(hand[key]>=word.count(key) for key in hand.keys())
```

This will return False if a letter appears more often in word than the value hand[letter].
If you want to have at least the amount of each letter in the word specified by the hand dictionary, just change it to `hand[key]<=word.count(key)`.
As far as I see the last way would be equivalent to the solution by thefourtheye using `Counter`